# How to add dropdown in header in crudbooster admin panel?

Tags: laravel, crudbooster

I'm new in crudbooster. I want to add my malls dropdown in the header, near to notification icon for selected privilege user. A data come from database only. and also update db column on selected mall id on select dropdown.